# firefox authentication window keeps popping up

Tags: firefox, authentication

I have a problem with my firefox browser in Ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I open a site from my corporate network the authentication popup window pops up continuously, even though i provide the user/password it doesn't take me through to the site but keeps coming back. I also use a windows machine and I do not see the issue there. Any ideas on how I can solve this.

Regards,
Ravi.

Comment: Are the settings for the two browsers identical (things like Javascript)?

Comment: Any specific settings to check? normally all settings are same.

Answer (score 0):

Check under Edit/Preferences/Advanced/network settings and see if there is any difference in a proxy use or settings.  Check what plugins are installed (some blockers may stop javascript from running).
User agent blocking is possible too.  Best to revisit the corporate requirements for conection -- they may give you a clue what to check.

---

Google firefox network authentication  to see some possible things to check.  There are many different situations.

Comment: Any other suggestions? This is happening only in ubuntu and firefox.
Works fine in windows and firefox.
Works fine in ubuntu and chrome.